# How can I recognize this app error and fix it

Tags: android, logcat

When I install apk and use it I get an error message

```
05-15 18:24:00.965 W/System.err(14449): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: id.co.aviana.brp
05-15 18:24:01.325 W/System.err(14449): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: id.co.aviana.brp
05-15 18:24:01.955 W/System.err(14449): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: id.co.aviana.brp
05-15 18:24:02.075 W/System.err(14449): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: id.co.aviana.brp
05-15 18:24:02.245 W/System.err(14449): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: id.co.aviana.brp
05-15 18:24:02.385 D/Wear_Controller(4835): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=id.co.aviana.brpreload
05-15 18:24:03.235 W/BroadcastQueueInjector(1303): Unable to launch app com.syntellia.fleksy.keyboard/10125 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:id.co.aviana.brpreload flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }: process is not permitted to autostart
05-15 18:24:03.395 I/Finsky  (14753): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.an.run(11): Package state data is missing for id.co.aviana.brpreload
05-15 18:24:14.745 I/ActivityManager(1303): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=id.co.aviana.brpreload cmp=id.co.aviana.brpreload/.SplashScreen} from uid 10082 on display 0
```

Then here is when I got the error message:

```
Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{3b5bee0e u0 id.co.aviana.brpreload/.MainActivity t334} time:33568210
05-15 18:26:45.295 E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper(3715): package name: id.co.aviana.brpreload
05-15 18:26:48.625 I/XiaomiFirewall(3548): firewall pkgName:id.co.aviana.brpreload, result:0x0
05-15 18:26:50.265 V/WindowManager(1303): not Base app: Adding window Window{1c9b8b6e u0 id.co.aviana.brpreload/id.co.aviana.brpreload.MainActivity} at 18 of 26
05-15 18:26:51.115 E/AmanattoDataUpdaterHelper(3715): package name: id.co.aviana.brpreload
05-15 18:26:53.445 V/WindowManager(1303): not Base app: Adding window Window{c599cff u0 id.co.aviana.brpreload/id.co.aviana.brpreload.MainActivity} at 19 of 27
05-15 18:26:53.675 W/System.err(15283):     at id.co.aviana.brpreload.FragmentPulsa$KirimTransaksi.doInBackground(FragmentPulsa.java:369)
05-15 18:26:53.675 W/System.err(15283):     at id.co.aviana.brpreload.FragmentPulsa$KirimTransaksi.doInBackground(FragmentPulsa.java:335)
05-15 18:26:53.735 V/WindowManager(1303): not Base app: Adding window Window{48bb7b8 u0 id.co.aviana.brpreload/id.co.aviana.brpreload.MainActivity} at 20 of 27
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be tagged with Java? And is this an app you made? Or just downloaded.

Comment: Sorry i am a newbie, i am not the one who made this app, they try to fix it but they still got nothing, i try to help them find any solution about this error.